# Make multiple html5-video start on click for iOS5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, ios5

I'm currently working on a page for playing different videos when you click an element. While it works beautifully on the computer, of iOS devices it does not. The problem is that when the element, in this case a button, is clicked, it shows the video but does not start playing, as it should. The script is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#video_1, #video_2').hide();

      $('.icon_1').click(function(){
            $('#video_2').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#video_1').fadeIn();
            });
      });

      $('.icon_2').click(function(){
            $('#video_1').fadeOut(function(){
            $('#video_2').fadeIn();
            });
        });

$('.icon_1').click(function(){

            $('.video_2').get(0).pause();
            $('.video_2').get(0).currentTime = 0;
            $('.video_1').get(0).play();

        });

$('.icon_2').click(function(){
            $('.video_1').get(0).pause();
            $('.video_1').get(0).currentTime = 0;
            $('.video_2').get(0).play();

        });
          });
```

and the html is

```
<button><div class="icon_1" id="mediaplayer" onclick="play">cadillac</div></button>
<button><div class="icon_2" id="mediaplayer2" onclick="play">nike</div></button>

<div id="video_1">
<video class="video_1" width="50%" height="50%"  controls poster="http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird.jpg" >    
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>

<div id="video_2">
<video class="video_2" width="50%" height="50%"  controls poster="images/BKG_JohnGT.png">
<source src="images/01.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
​</div>
```

It anyone could give me a function that could mak this happen, tht would be great

Comment: I think you have to actually have click on the video element on iOS mobile

Answer (score 3):

iOS does not support more than one video element in a page at one time. It doesn't even give you an error message - it will merely display the poster image (or first frame) and then fail to play, just as you describe.

Unfortunately, you can't do a true cross-fade, but you can come close. Start with only one video element attached to the DOM.  When switching from one video to another, you can fade the current video out, and then when it's done, remove it and add the second video. Apple has provided some [details and code samples](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html) on how to do this.

In theory, you should be able to grab a snapshot of the video frame in a canvas and swap that in for the video and fade the canvas out, but iOS doesn't support capturing video frames in a canvas either.

These and some other non-standard behaviors are described well in [this article](http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/).